# jquery disable one input based on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two inputs where one is disabled and alt tag is removed if user adds anything into another input. This part works fine. But i also want to disable this same input if value is predefined in first input. Sometimes first input is empty and user has to fill it, sometimes it has predefined value, so another input should be disabled and alt tag removed.

Tnx

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8aqyvqa/)

```js
$('.gsmhr').on('input', function() {
if ($(this).val().length)
$('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', true).val('').removeAttr("alt");
else $('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This works on user input<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
<br><br>
This should work if value is predefined<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="asdf" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
```

Comment: Can you explain what you need clearly?

Comment: I have a bunch of inputs in a large form, some of them need to be disabled if another fields has any value, but they are not next to each other, but are scattered all over form. Once user inputs all the fields and goes to next step, to review, he also has option to go back and change anything. The problem is, that those disabled fields are now enabled, even if control field has same value as user added it. Only when user changes anything in control field, that target field gets disabled again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.gsmhr').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length)
    $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', true).val('').removeAttr("alt"); // disable and clear other fields
  else $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', false);
}).trigger("input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This works on user input<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
<br><br> This should work if value is predefined<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="asdf" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
```

1. Use this context
2. Use `.trigger()` to fire input on load

Comment: I see now i was not clear enough with my question. Sorry about that. While code works here it doesn't work on my production. The issue might be that inputs are not together but are in separate div's. I updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e8aqyvqa/19/ to correctly show my situation. I also have three inputs that need to be disabled, but i don't think thats the problem.

Comment: @teva change your if condition to `if ($(this).val().length == 0)` to check for empty then disable

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work, but i was able to fix it with just adding .trigger to my initial code. Works great now, thank you. Here is working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e8aqyvqa/20/

Comment: i was trying to pass your idea to another similar code, but didn't work. Do you care to look at another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ly6u6dbj/ Same issue, when user inputs any field all others are disabled, but when predefined value is added, other fields are still active.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the inputs to check if there are any values set and use `$(this).next('.gsmslo1')` to target the proper next input:

```js
$('.gsmhr').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length) {
    $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', true).val('').removeAttr("alt"); // disable and clear other fields
  } else {
    $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
$('.gsmhr').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length) {
    $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', true).val('').removeAttr("alt"); // disable and clear other fields
  } else {
    $(this).next('.gsmslo1').prop('disabled', false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This works on user input<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
<br><br> This should work if value is predefined<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="asdf" class="gsmhr" maxlength="15" size="17" />
<input type="text" name="" value="" class="gsmslo1" alt="simple" maxlength="3" size="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function DisableEnableTextbox(currentElement){
      var value = $(currentElement).val();
        if (value.length) {
            $(currentElement).next(".gsmslo1").prop('disabled', true).val('');
        }
        else {
            $(currentElement).next(".gsmslo1").prop('disabled', false);
        }
  }

  $(".gsmhr").on("input", function() {
        DisableEnableTextbox(this);
  });

  $(".gsmhr").each(function(){
    DisableEnableTextbox(this);
  });
});
```

Refer [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/e8aqyvqa/16/)